# Focusing Stage doesn't actually focus

Tags: java, javafx, window, focus, stage

I have this code:

```
stage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
stage.setAlwaysOnTop(false);
stage.requestFocus();
```

But it seems like `requestFocus` does not work: the window just goes on top without getting focus.
How to focus the window too?

Comment: Doesn't putting the window on top means it has focus. What behavior would you have a `Stage` do when given focus?

Comment: In Windows, for example, the text in the title bar is grey instead of black.